# Inserting text alongside a checkbox in a Jtable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have been fiddling around with this for a while, and all the solutions and working examples I could find included check boxes rendered using the built-in Boolean TableCellRenderers, that is a cell could have only a check box. I didn't find any working example where there would be some text alongside that check box in that SAME cell, or more specifically a JCheckBox which allows a check box and a text.

Comment: With out even trying anything else, I suggest you start with [Using Custom Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Comment: I'd also be interested in knowing why you'd need to text associated with a checkbox in a table cell, as the column header should (in most cases) provide a description on the intent ... just saying

Comment: In additional, you could use another column to represent the text

Comment: As to the idea of using another column to represent the text - in principle that is possible, but it is not very convenient for my purpose.  There are column headers which describe what is in that column, but the thing is that there are also row headers (that is - the first column in the table), so each row is different. In each cell I have to specify stuff that describe what is relevant for that row. That text alongside the check box is essential.

Comment: Look it's your needs not mine, even with your expanded context, I'd still (personal) learn towards one column for the checkbox and for the associated text, but that's just me

Answer (score 1):

When your data/requirements doesn't fit within the default available functionality, you need to look towards providing a customised solution

I'd recommend you start by having a look at [Using custom renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public class Data {
        private String text;
        private boolean selected;

        public Data(String text, boolean selected) {
            this.text = text;
            this.selected = selected;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return selected;
        }

        public void setSelected(boolean state) {
            this.selected = state;
        }

    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {"Something"}, 0) {
                @Override
                public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                    return Data.class;
                }
            };
            model.addRow(new Object[]{new Data("Hello", true)});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{new Data("Goodbye", false)});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{new Data("Do you want to play a game?", true)});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{new Data("Yesturday", false)});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{new Data("Tomorrow", true)});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{new Data("Java", false)});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{new Data("Swift", false)});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{new Data("Helicopter", true)});


            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            table.setDefaultRenderer(Data.class, new DataTableCellRenderer());

            add(new JScrollPane(table));
        }

    }

    public class DataTableCellRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            if (isSelected) {
                setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
                setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            } else {
                setBackground(table.getBackground());
                setForeground(table.getForeground());
            }

            if (value instanceof Data) {
                Data data = (Data)value;
                setText(data.getText());
                setSelected(data.isSelected());
            }

            return this;
        }

    }

}
```

At this point, I'm left wondering if `JTable` is the best solution and if `JList` might be better

Of course, another option, which might work better with `JTable`, would be to devise a custom `TableModel` which could break down the data into separate columns...

[image: Custom table model]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public class Data {

        private String text;
        private boolean selected;

        public Data(String text, boolean selected) {
            this.text = text;
            this.selected = selected;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return selected;
        }

        public void setSelected(boolean state) {
            this.selected = state;
        }

    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            DataTableModel model = new DataTableModel();
            model.add(new Data("Hello", true));
            model.add(new Data("Goodbye", false));
            model.add(new Data("Do you want to play a game?", true));
            model.add(new Data("Yesturday", false));
            model.add(new Data("Tomorrow", true));
            model.add(new Data("Java", false));
            model.add(new Data("Swift", false));
            model.add(new Data("Helicopter", true));

            JTable table = new JTable(model);

            add(new JScrollPane(table));
        }

    }

    public class DataTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<Data> rows = new ArrayList<>(25);

        public void add(Data data) {
            int rowCount = getRowCount();
            rows.add(data);
            fireTableRowsInserted(rowCount, rowCount);
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            switch (column) {
                case 0: return "";
                case 1: return "Option";
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return rows.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0: return Boolean.class;
                case 1: return String.class;
            }
            return Object.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Data row = rows.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0: return row.isSelected();
                case 1: return row.getText();
            }
            return null;
        }



    }

}
```

IMHO, this is a better solution for using `JTable`